# Scroll the seekbar using accessbility

Tags: android, accessibility, seekbar, android-seekbar

I want to scroll the seekbar and perform the action at that point.Here is the node information iam getting from the app.

```
   className: android.widget.SeekBar; text: null; error: null; maxTextLength: -1; contentDescription: null; viewIdResName: com.sampleApp:id/duty_switch_go_home; checkable: false; checked: false; focusable: true; focused: false; selected: false; clickable: false; longClickable: false; contextClickable: false; enabled: true; password: false; scrollable: false; importantForAccessibility: true; actions: [AccessibilityAction: ACTION_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SELECT - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_CLEAR_SELECTION - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SHOW_ON_SCREEN - null, AccessibilityAction: ACTION_SET_PROGRESS - null]
```

Here is the image of the seekbar.  I want to switch from offline to online.

[image]

Iam able to move the seekbar to the exact online position. but it is not getting active.If i tap once on the seekbar then only it is going to active state.Here is the my code.

```
 String id =childNode.getViewIdResourceName().toString(); 
 if(id.equals("com.sampleApp:id/duty_switch_go_home")) 
 {
 Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                                arguments.putFloat(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_PROGRESS_VALUE, (float) 50.0);//
                                childNode.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction.ACTION_SET_PROGRESS.getId(), arguments);
 }
```

Iam geeting like this.

[image]

PLease any one help me to resolve my issue.